# How do I install a program from a executable CD?

Tags: 12.10, command-line, iso

Now by executable CD I mean a disk that usually would run and install a program but for some reason isn't. I would particularly like to know how to install it from the command line (terminal). Please do help. The program on the CD is an .iso file.

It is **not** a windows executable file it is an .iso file for the installation of the program MATLAB with the following contents:

- a x-install file
- a license text file
- a few octet-stream file
- some documentation (.pdf)
- some x-executable files
- plain text files
- icons

Comment: are you trying to re-install or repair the Ubuntu?

Comment: No this isn't Ubuntu on the CD otherwise I would have said it was a live CD for whichever version it was.

Comment: Executable CD, as in a Windows executable? What is the name of the program you are trying to install? What are the contents of the CD? Please edit your question and add more information about it. ISO files are not executable, they are meant to be burned to media or mounted to be read.

Comment: No not Windows executable. It is MATLAB the program and I will add some more detail.

Comment: Sorry to add to all the questions, but: you say that the program on the CD is an .iso file, but that would be an issue. Don't you mean you created the CD from a .iso file (in that case, it doesn't really matter), or is there an actual .iso file on the CD?

Comment: I created the CD from the .iso file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Mount the file on a local drive.

Make a mount point
For example:

```
mkdir /media/mathworks
```

Then mount the ISO to that directory. For example, If you have downloaded the ISO and it is in the home folder under the downloads folder and the ISO is called `matlab.iso`(In your case you need to move from CD Drive):

```
mount -t iso9660 -o loop ~/downloads/matlab.iso /media/mathworks
```

Now you can navigate there and run the installer

```
cd /media/mathworks  
./install
```

Comment: How do I mount the file onto a local drive? Do you mean just copy and paste the components of the decompressed .iso file in a local drive?

Comment: nope it should be all in one, just the compressed .iso file